# How to create (from local file) clickable label in PDF output use by anchor tag QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I would like to generate a PDF that has clickable elements (I entered the file access in each field) that take me to a specific file on the network, the link of which looks like this on the network: `\\xyz.xx.com\data\xyz.pdf`

I have already managed to make a link clickable with the following: `file:////xyzze.xy.com\data\xyz.PDF`

How can I shorten this link with the `<a href="file://///xyzze.xy.com\data\xyz.PDF">data</a>` html element?

I tried based on this, but it didn't work: https://github.com/elpaso/QGIS/commit/a33ab6fb3bbbac8f5a7328ca27e0f0d00eccba64?diff=split&w=1

Does you know a solution to this?